# How to add new property in existing object in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm making app with Firebase and AngularJS. I'm stuck on maybe simple maybe not - problem by adding new property in existing object in Firebase, here is what i mean:

```
    -K8cmeQRt4giLD9BHEEX {
        users: {
           age: 28,
           fname: John,
           lname: McGregor,
           id:{
               uid: id-hash
           }
         }
    }
-K8cmrrsDknx17ccjZ3d{
        users: {
           age: 35,
           fname: Ian,
           lname: Smith,
           id:{
               uid: id-hash
           }
         }
    }
```

My factory:

```
addToUserObject: function (calls) {
            var ref = new Firebase(globalFirebase);
            var append = ref.push();
            ref.orderByChild("users").startAt().on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                var val = snapshot.val();
                var aid = ref.getAuth();
                for(var key in val){
                    if (val[key].id.uid === aid.uid) {
                        append.parent().child('users').set(calls);
                    };
                }
            });
        }
```

But it still add object as new one, but not to existing one!
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Calling `set()` replaces the value at the location with the value/object you specify. So every time you call `append.parent().child('users').set(calls)` you replace the entire `users` node

If you want to add new properties (or update a subset of the properties) to an existing object, call the `update()` method. I'm not sure how it applies to your case, but something like `append.parent().child('users').update({ newCalls: calls })`.

If you're trying to add a new child node to a list, you'll want to use `push()`: `append.parent().child('users').push(calls)`. This will generate a new push ID, similar to the `-K8cmeQRt4giLD9BHEEX` value you already have.

Note that all of these and many more are covered in [Firebase's guide for JavaScript developers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/). I highly recommend you spend some time there.

Comment: Thank you. It helps me )

Answer (score 1):

To add the property `favoris` to the user object

```
function Add_user_favoris(){
        var db = firebase.database()
        var ref = db.ref();
        var usersRef = ref.child("users");
        // alanisawesome is the key of the object
        var hopperRef = usersRef.child("alanisawesome");
        hopperRef.update({
          "favoris": "list ,list list"
        });


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution of the issu:

```
getNativeUserObject: function (exp) {
            var ref = new Firebase(globalFirebase);
            var aid = ref.getAuth();
            ref.on('value', function (snap) {
                var data = snap.val();
                for(var key in data){
                    if (aid.uid === data[key].users.id.uid) {
                        data[key].users.calories = exp;
                        ref.child(key).update(data[key]);/*SOLUTION*/
                        window.location.reload();
                    };                  
                }
            });
        }
```

Frank: Thanks for answer! Really helpfull!